# Android PowerManager wakelock wont work withouth TOAST

Tags: android

I have made an app that wakes up the screen when it receives a text message. I came up with the following code to wake the screen.

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

        boolean isScreenOn = pm.isScreenOn();

    if(!isScreenOn ){

final PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "My tag");
        wl.acquire();

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "This is WAKEUP SCREEN", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Thread timer = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try {
                    sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }finally{
                    wl.release();
                }
            }
        };
        timer.start();
    }
```

Now the problem is that if I comment out or remove the statement `Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "This is WAKEUP SCREEN", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` my screen wont wakeup. I am not sure what is the problem here... and I am using android 2.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK|PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP` instead of just `PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK`, and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks... I will check this as soon as possible... But can you explain the reason behind this??

Comment: @AtifFarrukh: To quote [the docs for `ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP), "Normally wake locks don't actually wake the device, they just cause it to remain on once it's already on. Think of the video player app as the normal behavior. Notifications that pop up and want the device to be on are the exception; use this flag to be like them."